# How to fetch a value from a json object in logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to fetch a value of (RequesterObjectId) from a json output

[image: kusto query output]

I am using parsejson to iterate on the JSON object

[image: Parse JSON output]

however iam trying to use below expression but it doesnt get the value

[image: Expression]

Additional details

[image: ParseJSON output]

[image: No output]

ParseJSON setting

[image]

name variable setting

[image]

[image: FLow]

Comment: What's the name of the first step that returns the data?  You can do this very easily without all of the steps you're taking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however I am trying to use below expression but it doesn't get the value

Expression should be `body('Parse_JSON')?['RequesterObjectId']` but you are using `parse_JSON`.

[image]

In order to avoid this, you can directly enter the parameter from `Dynamic content` like below-

[image]

[image]

**Code view:**

```
{
"definition": {
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",   
"actions": {
"Initialize_variable": {
"inputs": {
"variables": [
{
"name": "Name",
"type": "string",
"value": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['RequesterObjectId']"
}
]
},
"runAfter": {
"Parse_JSON": [
"Succeeded"
]
},
"type": "InitializeVariable"
},
"Parse_JSON": {
"inputs": {  
"content": "@triggerBody()",
"schema": {
"properties": {
"RequesterObjectId": {
"type": "string"
}
},
"type": "object"
}
},
"runAfter": {},
"type": "ParseJson"
}
},
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"outputs": {},
"parameters": {},
"triggers": {
"manual": {
"inputs": {},
"kind": "Http",
"type": "Request"
}
}
},
"parameters": {} 
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

In Standard workflow, you should do the following-

[image]

First Initialize variable and then set that variable like below

[image]

[image]

In this way, you will get the output.

Comment: I dont know what i am doing wrong.. In the ParseJSON i ingest (body) of the kusto query output, Under additional details--- i have shown the outputs of ParseJSON and variable (name). i am not getting the output

Comment: You are adding small p instead of Cap. P in Parse_JSON

Comment: forgot to add... i am using dynamic content from ParseJSON (RequesterObjectId)... i have added additional screenshots

Comment: Can you share the design diagram where you are initializing variable and also the expression

Comment: what is the expression in value parameter

Comment: No expressions...just using dynamic content as you suggested (Image is added)  and even when using body('Parse_JSON')?['RequesterObjectId'] it doesnt give any output

Comment: what should i take as a value in set variable ? because when i am taking body('Parse_JSON')?['RequesterObjectId'] as a value it still comes null

Comment: First you need to initialize the variable and then set the variable. In set variable name, select your variable name and then in value take the Parse_JSON output from dynamic content

Comment: @gauravsharma try to change the schema in your `Parse_JSON` action, as per this data 
{
  "value": [
    {
      "RequesterObjectId": "afreen12"
    }
  ]
}
Now I have noticed that in your `Parse_JSON` action, you are inserting above value so, due to incorrect schema, its not giving you correct references in *Dynamic Content*, I have corrected as per your input value and then my flow looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/QV9HiOU.png) and [this](https://i.imgur.com/IWawuLU.png)